# Opening jQuery Colorbox with ASP Button OnClick

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, oracle

I am still pretty new to using jQuery to do anything, but I have had good luck with linking to Colorbox iFrames in the past.

Right now, I am trying to link a common ASP button to open up a Colorbox window.  I have tried searching all over but I can't seem to find the exact answer I'm needing.  Here is what I have so far, which definitely doesn't work at all.

```
 <div id="openColorbox">
        <asp:Button ID="NewRecordBTN" runat="server" Text="New Material Movement Request" onclick="NewRecordBTN_Click" />
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#openColorbox").click(function(){
            $.colorbox({ 
                  iframe: true, 
                   width: "80%", 
                  height: "80%", 
              transition: "fade" }));
    });
```

Trying to make the jQuery .click() function watch the "openColorbox" div that I created and open on click.  I also want to point the iFrame to another URL in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send to a URL within the jQuery Colorbox and reload the parent page after the transaction was completed via the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenCBox() 
    {
        $.colorbox({ href: "NewMMR.aspx", iframe: true, width: "40%", height: "70%", transition: "elastic", onClosed: function () { parent.location.reload(true); } });
    }
</script>
```

This will reload the parent page upon reload.  It also sends it to NewMMR.aspx when it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) event on button

EDIT:

Something like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="New`enter code here`RecordBTN" runat="server" Text="New Material Movement Request" onclick="NewRecordBTN_Click" OnClientClick="OpenColorBox()" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  function OpenColorBox()
  {
    $.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%", transition: "fade" });
  }    

</script>
```

I am not sure if you need server side event handling?

Comment: Nope, didn't change the outcome.  All it does when I click the button is postback the page.

Comment: Did you see the example? You need to create a function in JavaScript and assign function into OnClientClick event handler.

Comment: Oooh yeah that did it.  It makes the ColorBox popup for like .25 seconds and disappear right away presumably because there is no content it is supposed to display yet.  Where would I through the URL in to display in the ColorBox?